# joint two sentences with "which" and "will"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

> This method suffers from high computation difficulty.
>
> The high-computation difficulty will require high efforts.

I would like to join them in one sentence using which and will:

My try:

> This method suffers from high computation difficulty which will require high efforts.

Is my structure correct?.

Comment: Your sentence is tautological, and **high efforts** is not idiomatic, but your use of **which** and **will** is correct enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand slightly on the comment, your use of "which" is correct. The use of a relative clause in a non-restrictive sense is equivalent to "and".  Optionally you insert a comma before which:

> ... , which ...  [is equivalent to]
>    ..., and it ...

As noted in the comments, the sentence is "tautological". You are essentially saying "This difficult thing is difficult", and the phrase "high efforts" is not idiomatic.  You could express the same concept in a simpler form.

> This method is computationally demanding.

This combines the notions of "difficulty" and "requiring great effort" into a single word.